# sound-juicer does not load CD info from Musicbrainz

Tags: sound-juicer

sound-juicer says it cannot find CD info in `Musicbrainz`, however pressing `edit` opens Musicbrainz page of a CD with all information.

There is a know [sound-juicer bug](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2011/06/13/sound-juicer-no-longer-retrieves-track-names-when-you-extract-audio-cds) caused by `Musicbrainz` API change, however the solution given did not solve the problem for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

What did help was installing `ruby-discid` package from musicbrainz ppa manually

`sudo apt-get remove sound-juicer
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phw/musicbrainz
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get install sound-juicer
sudo apt-get install ruby-discid`

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work unfortunately.